# pyautogui comparar resultado CTRL + V

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

Tenho o seguinte código

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(612, 269)
pyautogui.doubleClick()
copiar = pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
colar = pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
resultado = colar
print(resultado)
```

porem o meu print está retornando "None". Sei que eu poderia mostrar o resultado do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> direto, mas eu quero fazer uma estrutura de repetição com a condicional

```
carregando = 'carregada '
pyautogui.moveTo(612, 269)
pyautogui.doubleClick()
copiar = pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
colar = pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
resultado = colar
if copiar == carregando:
  copiar = pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
```

Comment: O que exatamente você está tentando fazer? A linha pyautogui.hotkey não retorna true ou false, logo essa comparação que você está tentando fazer nunca vai funcionar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Então, preciso saber se o conteúdo dentro do meu ctrl+v é igual a "carregada ". Se ele for igual, deverá continuar copiando e colando aquele ponto especifico. Se ele não for igual, vai passar para outro comando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhando o método hotkey da classe pyautogui é possível verificar que ele não **retorna nada**, logo sua comparação acima não vai funcionar.

Sugiro pegar o valor que foi copiado para a área de transferência (Clipboard) e comparar se foi carregado ou não.

Usando a biblioteca **Tkinter** (Python 2) ou **tkinter** (Python 3)

```
import tkinter as tk
r = tk.Tk()
dado_copiado = r.clipboard_get()
```

Ou utilizando a biblioteca win32clipboard

```
import win32clipboard
dado_copiado = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. E como consigo comparar o que tenho dentro do ctr+v?

preciso saber se o conteúdo dentro do meu ctrl+v é igual a "carregada ". Se ele for igual, deverá continuar copiando e colando aquele ponto especifico. Se ele não for igual, vai passar para outro comando.

Comment: Ainda não sei exatamente o que você está programando. Se quiser pegar o conteúdo que foi copiado para o clipboard e comparar se o dados foi "carregado" através do Ctrl+C, pode usar a biblioteca tkinter.

Comment: Conseguiria comparar o resultado do meu Ctrl+C com  o contudo de alguma variável?

Comment: Somente para ajudar alguém que possa ter a mesma dúvida em algum momento. Poderia sim comprar o resultado do "Ctrl + C". No exemplo acima você tem a variável dado_copiado. Podemos usar ela para fazer o comparativo em python com a sua segunda possível variável, Exemplo: if dado_copiado == segunda_variavel: #o if compara as duas variáveis e daí em diante você segue com o pretendido.